# WLAN Router authentification

Tags: network, authentication, wifi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I ensure that I connect to the right wireless Access Point?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/how-can-i-ensure-that-i-connect-to-the-right-wireless-access-point)

Is it true, that WLAN routers aren't authenticated by clients? The only "authentication" is SSID and field strength?

Comment: Just found an interesting link: http://www.andrewmccormack.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=108:why-wpa-doesnt-protect-you-against-sidejacking&catid=35:security

It's only secure as long as the PSK isn't known. If it is known like in many hotels, there's no router authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The SSID is more about identification of the network, not authentication.

Wireless authentication is done usually in either of these 3 ways:

- Open System authentication: no authentication done
- Shared Key authentication: Done with cryptographic handshakes between client and AP based on some shared secret - of course trust is on the assumption that the key is shared only between these two parties. In WPA/WPA2 there is mutual authentication, in WEP only client authentication is done.
- EAP authentication: Using a radius server, different ways it can be done, can be based on certificates etc, no need for one shared secret for everyone. Mutual authentication is usually done.

Comment: Is this authentication used by common clients and SOHO Routers? I've never seen a certificate or key. Is it automatically saved after first login?

Comment: If wpa/wpa2 is used then there is going to be a key or certificate of some sort. Are you talking about open wifi networks that don't use such mechanisms?

Comment: Yes or if the attacker got the PSK. Added a link to my question above. Quite interesting...

Comment: Edited the answer to cover more possibilities.